# Source for skipping the first Shaar of Chovos HaLevavos

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, jewish-books, mussar-ethics

I heard today in Shul that there is a custom to "skip" the first Shaar of Chovos HaLevavos and substitute it by the Kuzari or the Mesilas Yesharim instead. Does anyone know what is the source for this?

Comment: This part of the general [Jewish anti-philosophical school that has been increasingly prominent since the 13th century](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73525/8775).

Comment: highly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5459/8775.

Comment: Note the Shela reccomended the study of Hovot Halevavot's Shaar HaYihud : של"ה עשרה מאמרות מאמר ראשון:  
על כן חל החיוב להיות בקי במופתים של חובת הלבבות, ויהיו מובנים בלב היטב היטב, וכל שער היחוד יהיה בלב וזכרון מיוחד,

Comment: If you have a copy of the Chovot Halevavot with the commentary of the Lev Tov, he brings pages of quotes of Rabbis from previous generations about this.

Comment: not everyone is capable of benefiting from it. but many people including myself got alot out of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One 18th century source for this is the [Noda BiYehudah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechezkel_Landau) (Mahadura Kamma OH 35):

> אמנם ילמוד דברי תורה שיש בהם ממש...וג"כ ספרי מוסר חובת הלבבות מן אחר שער היחוד עד גמירא
>
> However, a person should learn Torah which has substance...and also ethical work [such as] Hoveot Halevavot [starting] **from after Sha'ar HaYihud**, until its end.

The Seer of Lublin (18th century) is quoted [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_4240_311.pdf#xml=http://hebrewbooks.org/hilite.aspx?pgnum=311&hilite=e31adef5-7bc3-4dce-bd1b-dd808eb34d09&toolbar=1&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&view=FitH) as saying that laypeople shouldn't learn it since they will not understand it..

R. Moshe Tsuriel [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_48849_199.pdf#xml=http://hebrewbooks.org/hilite.aspx?pgnum=199&hilite=98f010af-d2b3-45a3-9dca-c33dfd634e75&toolbar=1&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&view=FitH) cites a saying in the name of the Vilna Gaon, that studying Kuzari is preferable to studying Sha'ar HaYihud.

Comment: The choice for Kuzari is natural; he was an anti-intellectual thinker who valued experiential evidence over the Sha'ar HaYihud's attempts at rigorous philosophical proofs. The former is much more consistent with the anti-intellectual school. Mesillay Yesharim would be a similar alternative; (although MY is not theological or philosophical, so it isn't really a replacement for Shaar HaYihud, since it is written on a different topic).

Comment: +1. On regard the choice for Kuzari or MY I was thinking something close to that.... but, on the other hand, would there be an actually source quoting this substitution as a minhag?

Comment: @RenatoGrun Added a reference regarding Kuzari. I don't know how reliable the author is though. He implies that the Shela opposes the study of Shaar HaYihud, when in reality the Shelah writes: חל החיוב להיות בקי במופתים של חובת הלבבות, ויהיו מובנים בלב היטב היטב, וכל שער היחוד יהיה בלב וזכרון מיוחד

Comment: Thanks for that. I think the source referring to Kuzari is the siddur haGra mentioned there. If you could be able to link it to the post, it would be a greatly appreciated. If you can't, I think this answer already fully answers me and this would suffice for now.